# How to sum up the previous cells using sumproduct?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, product, sumproduct

How to sum up the previous cells using sumproduct ?

For example,
here is my numbers in a column

```
0.111
0.222
0.333 
0.444
0.555
```

How can I find `(0.111x0.222)+(0.111x0.222x0.333) till (0.111x0.222x0.333x0.444x0.555)` without creating one more table ?

Comment: What is your end result here? Just a single sum?

Comment: yes! The end result is just a single sum!

Comment: And you want to discard `0.111` on itself?

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with @JvdV's solution if you wrap it in Sum?

Comment: Me neither @TomSharpe, I deleted it myself since I don't know if `0.111` should be accounted for too. Seems logical.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your choice of values. Here they form a linear progression, though it would be useful to know if that's mere coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

johnylulu hello,
I just wrote a built-in function for you.  If you pass your range as parameter to this function, it will return you the sum you need.

```
    Function mySumProduct(inputRange As Range) As Double
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim temporarySum As Double
    temporarySum = 0
    temporaryResult = 1
    Arr = inputRange.Value
    Dim i As Integer
       For i = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2) - 1
          temporaryResult = temporaryResult * Arr(1, i)
          mySumProduct = temporarySum + temporaryResult * Arr(1, i + 1)
          temporarySum = mySumProduct
       Next i
    mySumProduct = temporarySum
    End Function
```